# Getting Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OralceDriver'

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I am new to *Spring* and *Hibernate* frameworks. Actually almost I finished up developing sample application but I'm getting an exception related to database. 
I tried some solutions to resolve that exception but I couldn't.

The exception thrown:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OralceDriver'
```

I have added the *ojdbc14.jar* under *lib* folder and also in Tomcat *lib* directory, but still getting the same exception.

Comment: Can you look inside the jar if the class is in it?

Comment: Yeah...i can see classes in the jar. I checked the Oracle connection too. It's running...I dono y i am getting this error... do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in you driver class declaration, it should be:

- `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

instead of (note the *cl lc* characters index)

- `oracle.jdbc.driver.OralceDriver`

Comment: Hey, great work man. Resolved the exception. I didn't see this typo anyway thanks for you. You are genius

Comment: You are always welcome, and will be pleased if you upvote the answer :)